# How to force FindClusters to return a specific number of clusters?

Tags: cluster-analysis

I am using FindClusters with the Method -> "KMedoids" option. I am specifying a desired number of clusters. It returns with many fewer than the desired number. Is there a way to force it to return the desired number? For reference a code snippet is

```
    nclusters = 1207;
    Length /@ {vectors, weights}
    weighteddata = WeightedData[vectors, weights];
    clusters = FindClusters[weighteddata, nclusters, Method -> "KMedoids"];
    Length[clusters];
```

output is

```
{58852, 58852}

453
```

All of the elements in vectors are distinct, so it is unclear why it finds only 453 clusters. The documentation says it will partition into "at most" nclusters, but does not say whether or how one can force a specific number of clusters.

Any help would be appreciated.

In response to a request, here is a worked example.

```
n = 10000;
k = 1000;
vectors = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, 3}];
weights = RandomInteger[{1, 1000}, n];
clusters = 
  FindClusters[WeightedData[vectors, weights], k, 
   Method -> "KMedoids"];
Length[clusters]
```

output is

```
427
```

Comment: Please provide a runnable example.

Comment: The example above requires 58852 vectors of length 3. I am not sure how to provide that here.

Comment: `RandomInteger`, `RandomReal` or some kind of function like that can be used to generate data. `SeedRandom` can make sure that everyone sees the same data.

Comment: I have added a worked example.